# remove an empty string from array of strings - JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array `["Lorem", "", "ipsum"]`. I would like to remove the empty string from this array and get `["Lorem", "ipsum"]`.

Is there any way to do this without using the loop and traversing through each element and removing it?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You may use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

```
var newArray = oldArray.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
```

[The MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) has a workaround for IE8 compatibility. You might also use a good old loop if you're not going to use `filter` anywhere else, there's no problem with looping...

Comment: quote "there's no problem with looping...", well, except that looping can (not always) be very slow. have you every tried to supplement the native indexOf() function with a loop in js-fiddle. Lets just say indexOf is magnitudes faster.

Answer (score 13):

If you use Javascript 1.6 (probably wont work on IE8 or less) you can use

```js
arr.filter(Boolean) //filters all non-true values
```

eg.

```js
console.log([0, 1, false, "", undefined, null, "Lorem"].filter(Boolean));
// [1, "Lorem"]
```

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative is to use the jquery's [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function:

```
var newArray = $.map( oldArray, function(v){
  return v === "" ? null : v;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function cleanArray(actual)
{
    var newArray = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i<actual.length; i++)
    {
        if (actual[i])
        {
            newArray.push(actual[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

$(function()
{
    var old = ["Lorem", "", "ipsum"];

    var newArr = cleanArray(old);

    console.log(newArr)
});
</script>
```

**Without Loop**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function()
{
    var arr = ["Lorem", "", "ipsum"];

    arr = $.grep(arr,function(n){
        return(n);
    });

    console.log(arr)
});
</script>
```

Both is tested.

Answer (score 0):

var arr = [ a, b, c, , e, f, , g, h ];

arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(n){ return (n); });

arr is now [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g];