# javascript check if value has at least 2 or more words

Tags: javascript, regex, string, input

I have a field that you enter your name in and submit it. I would like the receive peoples first and last names and to do this i need to check if the value contains at least 2 words. This is what I am using right now but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function validateNameNumber(name) {
    var NAME = name.value;
    var matches = NAME.match(/\b[^\d\s]+\b/g);
    if (matches && matches.length >= 2) {
        //two or more words
        return true;
    } else {
        //not enough words
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *"doesn't seem to work"* mean? Show your input and explain both the expected and observed output. Your code works for me.

Comment: Why are you downvoting every answer?

Comment: @lvogel: He's not, I am because they're really bad answers.

Comment: @cookiemonster So provide an answer on yourself.

Comment: @lvogel: No, not until the OP has answered my question above.

Comment: @cookiemonster input is from a textfield. when I test it, say if the input was "a" it will say it doesn't work (which is good). if the input is "a " it says it works. (not good). if the input is "a a" it says it doesn't work. (very bad)

Comment: You should probably be looking for groupings of the characters you *do* want instead of those that you don't want. For example, `/\w+/g`

Comment: Your solution works with an input of `"a "` and `"a a"`

Comment: I spot #20 of the [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) here.

Answer (score 24):

```
str.trim().indexOf(' ') != -1 //there is at least one space, excluding leading and training spaces
```

Comment: great answer for validating a user entered both first and last name.

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution (not 100% reliable, since "foo   " returns 4, as @cookiemonster mentioned):

```
var str = "Big Brother";
if (str.split(" ").length > 1) {
    // at least 2 strings
}
```

The better solution:

```
var str = "Big Brother";
var regexp = /[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+/g;
if (regexp.test(str)) {
    // at least 2 words consisting of letters
}
```

Comment: `"foo    ".split(' ').length; // 6`

Comment: @cookiemonster That's why I provide another solution.

Comment: @cookiemonster But I think it's unlikely that a user really enters "Foo       " where it says "enter your name".

Comment: Your other solution is incorrect in various ways. Test your answer.

Comment: What? Have you missed the point of the question? He wants to validate that there are two words. I gave an example of one word that gives a false positive using your solution.

Comment: I think you should prefer ```\s+``` to a space in your regexp.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the String.Split() method:

```
function validateNameNumber(name) {
    var NAME = name.value;
    var values = name.split(' ').filter(function(v){return v!==''});
    if (values.length > 1) {
        //two or more words
        return true;
    } else {
        //not enough words
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you were to pass "John Doe" as the name value, values would equal {"john", "doe"}

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

**Edit:** Added filter to remove empty values. Source: [remove an empty string from array of strings - JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453702/3033053)

Comment: No issue with being downvoted, but an explanation as to why would be nice.  Seems funny that 3 of 4 answers were all downvoted at once without any explanation...

Comment: `"foo     ".split(' ').length; // 6`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from your snippet

```
var matches = NAME.match(/\b[^\d\s]+\b/g);
```

to this

```
var matches = NAME.match(/\S+/g);
```

or to this, if numbers should be excluded

```
var matches = NAME.match(/\b([a-z]+)\b/gi);
```

Side (funny) note: Your snippet works just fine. Check the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/seheniwukupi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Why? It seems wants to exclude numbers. You're just changing the criteria, but it's ultimately the same solution.

Comment: @cookiemonster (1) He said at the end _it doesn't seem to work_ and that's just enough to not analyze every line (2) I saw the other answers being down-voted even they actually are ok (not seeing the rep of OP) so (3) I thought let's give a different answer.

Comment: The other answers are not OK, but yours is better, which is why I didn't downvote it. However I don't think you need to necessarily change the critera, though I think it would be better for the OP to explain the exact criteria in detail.

Comment: @cookiemonster The funny part is that OPs snippet is working fine. Check this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/seheniwukupi/1/edit) or maybe I'm missing something :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. He claims that it doesn't work with certain input, but it works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution overall (see the other answers), but one that shows how to count the number of times a regexp matches a string:

```
function validateNameNumber(name) {
    var nameValue = name.value;
    var regexp = /\b[^\d\s]+\b/g;
    var count = 0;
    while (regexp.exec(nameValue)) ++count;
    if (count >= 2) {
        //two or more words
        return true;
    } else {
        //not enough words
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just check for whitespace by running a for loop.

```
var correctFormat = false;
for (var i = 0; i = i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name[i] === " ") {
       correctFormat = true;
    }
}
if (correctFormat === false) {
    alert("You entered an invalid name");
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

If the name doesn't have a space, knowing that there is a space between the first and last name, it would `alert("You entered an invalid name");`