# WooCommerce force full name in First Name field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On our WooCommerce site, we have removed the last name field on checkout and uses the first name field for the full name. This makes it easier for the customer, but a lot of customers just enter their first name, which causes some problems. Is it possible, in some way, to check if the first name input has 2 words (to check for full name), and if not, throw a custom WooCommerce error notice?

Any help or point int he right direction is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38431726/8913606

Comment: Is there any reason for removing the last name field ?

Comment: Please check this https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: We have removed it, to make the checkout more simple, and less fields for the customers to fill out.
And thanks for the links, but this doesn't seem to be a proper solution, as we need it to throw the standard WooCommerce error.